# Find href attribute values that do not contain “javascript:”

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, regex

I have a RegEx which nicely finds the href's in a URL:

```
<[aA][^>]*? href=[\"'](?<url>[^\"]+?)[\"'][^>]*?>
```

However, I want it to NOT find any href that contains the text, 'javascript:' in it.

The reason is that I sometimes need to mod the href and sometimes don't. When there is a 'javascript:' text in the href I want it not to be found by the regex.

(ASP.NET, C#)

Comment: In theory it is some kind of complex to consider all kinds of possibilities how `javascript:` can occur (see http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html). But in your case `(?<url>(?!javascript:)[^\"]+?)` may suffice.

Comment: PERFECT. That worked. How do I mark this comment as the answer in StackOverFlow.com?

Comment: Gumbo, post the comment as an answer, then BahaiResearch.com mark as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really wouldn't recommend using a regexp for this, since HTML isn't regular and there are no end of edge cases to cater for. If at all possible, please use an HTML parser. I think you'll find it a lot less grief.

Comment: It works in this case (http://BiblePro.BibleOcean.com) because I control the html structure. It's a single page AJAX app.

Answer (score 0):

A word `javascript` can be written in other ways. Look at [ha.ckers.org](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) article.
Simple excluding `javascript` word dot't provide you safety at all.